# How to match index between two numpy ndArray and sort them?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy ndArray. They contain x,y value in cartesian coordinates.

```
parent =
[[ 10  234]
[ 20  100]
[ 30  100]
[ 40  345]
[  5  100]
[ -45 110]]
```

Now let say based on some random algorithm I have found my child element where y value is 100.

so my child element looks like this:

```
child=
[[ 20  100]
[  5  100]
[ 30  100]]
```

As my algorithm changed the order, I want to create a function that will give me a child element properly sorted based on the parent's element.

So my child will look like this:

```
child=
[[ 20  100]
[ 30  100]
[  5  100]]
```

`30,100` comes before `5,100` as `30,100` has lower indexing value . `20,100` remain in the same position as it has a lower index value among all.

I am having difficulties to achieve this. I will be so glad if you help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by looping over the entire parent list and only keeping the ones that are also in the childs list:

```
parent = [[10, 234],
          [20, 100],
          [30, 100],
          [40, 345],
          [5, 100],
          [-45, 110]]

child = [[20, 100],
         [5, 100],
         [30, 100]]

print([i for i in parent if i in child])

>>>[[20, 100], 
    [30, 100], 
    [5, 100]]
```